# listing products after its parent(category)

Tags: php, mysql, loops, join, parent-child

I'm relatively new to php and I am using oscommerce to create a list of category's, subcategory's, and the products available in the subcategory's, in a report. I've managed to create the list of category's, with the child(subcategory) after it. I have hit a dead end in trying to list the products after the subcategory's. Here is a snip of the coding:

```
function category_list( $category_parent_id = 0 )
{
$sql  = 'select cd.categories_name,c.categories_id, c.parent_id, c.sort_order from ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES . ' c, ' . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . ' cd where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id AND c.parent_id='.$category_parent_id;
$res  = tep_db_query( $sql );
$cats = array();
 while ( $cat = tep_db_fetch_array( $res ) )
  {
    $cats[] = $cat;
  }
 if (count($cats) == 0)
    {
  return '';
  }
 $list_items = array();
foreach ( $cats as $cat )
 {
$list_items[] = '<tr class="dataTableRow"><td class="dataTableContent">'; 
if($category_parent_id != 0)$list_items[] = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
if($category_parent_id == 0)$list_items[] = '<b>';
$list_items[] = $cat['categories_name'];


if($category_parent_id == 0)$list_items[] = '</b>';
$list_items[] = '</td><td class="dataTableContent">'; 
$list_items[] = category_list( $cat['categories_id'] );
$list_items[] = '</td></tr>'; 
}
$list_items[] = '';
return implode( '', $list_items );

}  
echo category_list();
```

For listing products, I have two tables that will need to be used, `product_to_cat`, and `prod_descrip`, joined by using the `product_id` field. For it to be listed in the correct parent, the `product_to_cat` and `cat` table are joined with the `category_id`. How would I go about printing the correct products in the correct category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the tables look like in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4de3/1/0),
then this is just a simple join between all tables

```
select c.parent_id, c.categories_id, cd.categories_name,
       p.product_id, pd.description
from categories c
join categories_description cd on cd.categories_id = c.categories_id
left join product_to_cat p on p.category_id = c.categories_id
left join prod_descrip pd on pd.product_id = p.product_id
order by c.parent_id, c.categories_id, p.product_id
```

I don't know how the sort_order fits in this picture.

If you want the products for one category only, do the following select in your loop

```
select p.product_id, pd.description
from product_to_cat p
left join prod_descrip pd on pd.product_id = p.product_id
where p.category_id = $cat['categories_id']
```

Comment: is there any way of running this in a seperate query, instead of using join, simply to help performance?

Comment: @user1879415 You can always split a join and do the join with php. But that requires additional queries, which is usually slower than a real join. Usually, it's better to let the DB make the join and concentrate on table layout and indexes. How long does the query take in your environment?

Comment: it takes a while to load up, is there another way of running a seperate query in the same loop?

Comment: @user1879415 You can do a select for the appropriate products only, of course. Please see the updated answer.